# Where to put Android application initialisation code?

Tags: android, process, android-activity

Quick question about Android application initialisation.
Very often the initialisation tasks are placed inside main activity onCreate/onResume methods.

Now the problem is, I cannot be guaranteed that the main activity code is always run.

For instance:
I have MainActivity with a button that triggers AnotherActivity by using intents:

`this.startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class)`

Now imagine the user has tapped the button and the application is put into background when the users navigates forward to another application or something.

After a while, because of OS resource policy, the application process could be killed.

When I go back to the application, the process is restarted but only AnotherActivity is instantiated and "run". So the initialisation code is skipped.

I thought that Application.onCreate could be a good choice but it should not contain to much time consuming code.

I was handed over some project which main activity is SplashActivity, that initialises some core application components and sometimes, after the process is restarted, the application breaks due to this behaviour.

This is what happens:

```
05-21 23:14:30.992 D/TESTAPP (22340): onCreate
05-21 23:14:31.002 D/TESTMAIN(22340): onCreate(null)
05-21 23:14:31.032 D/TESTMAIN(22340): onStart
05-21 23:14:31.032 D/TESTMAIN(22340): onResume
05-21 23:14:36.922 D/TESTMAIN(22340): onPause
05-21 23:14:36.932 D/TESTOTHER(22340): onCreate(null)
05-21 23:14:36.932 D/TESTOTHER(22340): Message: Hello World
05-21 23:14:36.952 D/TESTOTHER(22340): onStart
05-21 23:14:36.952 D/TESTOTHER(22340): onResume
05-21 23:14:37.342 D/TESTMAIN(22340): onSaveInstanceState
05-21 23:14:58.312 D/TESTOTHER(22340): onPause
05-21 23:14:58.812 D/TESTOTHER(22340): onSaveInstanceState
05-21 23:19:47.342 D/TESTAPP (24928): onCreate
05-21 23:19:47.342 D/TESTOTHER(24928): onCreate(not null)
05-21 23:19:47.342 D/TESTOTHER(24928): Message: null
05-21 23:19:47.392 D/TESTOTHER(24928): onStart
05-21 23:19:47.392 D/TESTOTHER(24928): onRestoreInstanceState
05-21 23:19:47.392 D/TESTOTHER(24928): onResume
```

TESTAPP is the log tag for Application.
TESTMAIN is for the main activity.
TESTOTHER for another launched from the main activity button

After the application was put to the background (see 23:14:58) I have put some memory pressure on the OS by running some other apps and after few minutes the process was killed (I'm not sure if the process was killed due to memory problems or some timeout).

Anyway, I used adb shell and ps command to discover when the process was gone and than navigated back to the application (see 23:19:47). No trace of TESTMAIN.

The main activity simply sets some static String to Hello World.
This string is the consumed by another activity. As the process was restarted, Hello World is gone.

The code:

```
public class StaticContainer {
    public static String Message;
}

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "TESTAPP";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TESTMAIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onCreate(%s)", savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
        StaticContainer.Message = "Hello World";

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            Button other = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.other);
            other.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtherActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}

public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TESTOTHER";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onCreate(%s)", savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + StaticContainer.Message);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
    ...the rest is the same as for the MainActivity (the only item missing is the button and its handler.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you are referring to?

Comment: I just did. Thank you.

Comment: The code is more or less what is given by Eclipse template project + additional logging + the button that launches another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store primative data types that you want to setup for use by other activities. These values can be retrieved by any other activity in your app, and remain available regardless of any activities getting destroyed.

For example, to set a string value in a shared preferences called "app_values":

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_values", MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("my_key_string", "Hello World").commit();
```

To retrieve that string value from the shared preferences called "app_values":

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_values", MODE_PRIVATE);
String myString = sharedPreferences.getString("my_key_string", "Default value if key not found");
```

Comment: Yes, for some cases using SharedPreferences may be a solution. But I have used simple static string property for demonstrating purposes only. My initialisation code is more complex, it involves initialisation of the services by providing context, setting some other static members. Most of them cannot be put into SharedPreferences. Thanks for the help.